# Removing TextEditingController which is used in ListView

Tags: flutter

Here is my code for reproduction: [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/56560d6da058fa0b763190d13365efc9)

When you add new "field" (by clicking to action button), and then removes it (via red icon), it throws error, that TextEditingController has been used after it was disposed. It looks like that even after rebuilding the ListView widget (by setState), it renders a field, but the controller is already disposed. For now, I solved it by disposing the TextEditingController after 500 ms.

```dart
final controller = stropheForms[index].controller;
setState(() {
  stropheForms.removeAt(index);
  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), ()
  {
    controller.dispose();
  });
});
```

Although I see this as hack and not good solution. What is the correct solution for this problem?

Comment: Your DartPad contains errors, you should init your controllers like `final _controller = TextEditingController();` and then dispose them properly in an overrided `dispose` method.

Comment: @PeterKoltai the error is the point of this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback`.
This callback is run during a frame, just after the persistent frame callbacks (which is when the main rendering pipeline has been flushed).

```
   onTap: () {
                final controller = stropheForms[index].controller;
                setState(() {
                  stropheForms.removeAt(index);
                });
                WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                  controller.dispose();
                });
              });
```

TO know more [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html)